# PHP encode/decode

Tags: php, decode, encode

I had this code:

```
eval(str_rot13('shapgvba purpx_sbbgre(){tybony $nz_bcgvba;$y=\'<n uers="uggc://jjj.penmlkugzy.pbz" gnetrg="_oynax">CFQ gb UGZY PFF</n>\';$s=GRZCYNGRCNGU.\'/sbbgre.cuc\';$sq=sbcra($s,\'e\');$p=sernq($sq,svyrfvmr($s));spybfr($sq);vs(fgecbf($p,$y)==0){rpub($nz_bcgvba[\'phfgbz\'][\'cevinpl\']);qvr;}}purpx_sbbgre();'));
```

I used to decode it with http://www.unphp.net/

Which became this code:

```
<?php function check_footer() {
    global $am_option;
    $l = '<a href="http://www.crazyxhtml.com" target="_blank">PSD to HTML CSS</a>';
    $f = TEMPLATEPATH . '/footer.php';
    $fd = fopen($f, 'r');
    $c = fread($fd, filesize($f));
    fclose($fd);
    if (strpos($c, $l) == 0) {
        echo ($am_option['custom']['privacy']);
        die;
    }
}
function check_footer() {
    global $am_option;
    $l = '<a href="http://www.crazyxhtml.com" target="_blank">PSD to HTML CSS</a>';
    $f = TEMPLATEPATH . '/footer.php';
    $fd = fopen($f, 'r');
    $c = fread($fd, filesize($f));
    fclose($fd);
    if (strpos($c, $l) == 0) {
        echo ($am_option['custom']['privacy']);
        die;
    }
}
check_footer();
```

Can someone help me how can I encode this back? I mean I changed somethings but dont know how to encode in similar language/code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rot13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) just shifts ascii letters 13 characters. Since there are 26 letters in the ASCII alphabet, this means shifting them 13 characters again will reverse the operation. Since non-ascii-letters will be ignored by the operation altogether, the reverse of rot13 is just rot13 again, as you can see below:

```
> $x='shapgvba purpx_sbbgre(){tybony $nz_bcgvba;$y=\'<n uers="uggc://jjj.penmlkugzy.pbz" gnetrg="_oynax">CFQ gb UGZY PFF</n>\';$s=GRZCYNGRCNGU.\'/sbbgre.cuc\';$sq=sbcra($s,\'e\');$p=sernq($sq,svyrfvmr($s));spybfr($sq);vs(fgecbf($p,$y)==0){rpub($nz_bcgvba[\'phfgbz\'][\'cevinpl\']);qvr;}}purpx_sbbgre();';
> var_dump($x === str_rot13(str_rot13($x)));
bool(true)
```

Comment: no you understand not correctly, I want same code but changed only domain names, can you help me?

Comment: Get the decoded version, change the domain names, then do str_rot13 on the changed string.

Comment: If you  change any encoded text after decoding the text, you simply apply rot13 again. Then you can replace the existing rot13 text with your text, and it will update.

Comment: so how can I rot13 again?

Comment: By use of the `str_rot13` function you already know and love.